# Symfony translation only show english

Tags: symfony, internationalization, translation, symfony-2.3

I try to translate website with user language.

in my config.yml:

```
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    #esi: ~
    translator: { fallbacks: [en] }
```

I added messges.en.yml and messages.it.yml under app/resources/translations.

When i visit the page with Italian browser i see english translations.

Following the symfony book i added this event subscriber:

```
namespace AppBundle\Service;

use AppBundle\Controller\TokenAuthenticatedController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class LanguageListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $user_lang = $request->getPreferredLanguage();
        $request->setLocale($user_lang);
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            KernelEvents::CONTROLLER => 'onKernelController',
        );
    }
}
```

but i continue to see only english...

Some tip?

Comment: Cleaned the cache? `rm -rf app/cache/*`

Comment: Are you sure `$user_lang` has the proper value? perhaps `getPrefferedLanguage` isn't working as intended and you're hitting your "fallback" logic?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create routes with defined **_locale** like this

```
@Route("/{_locale}/post/list", name="post_index", defaults={"_locale": "en"}, requirements={"_locale": "en|fr|nl" })
```

Don't forget to import Route class for annotations and clear cache.